# Windows Phone 8 HttpClient and POSTing JSON

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, dotnet-httpclient

I am quite new to C# and WP8 in general. I am currently finding difficulties in doing a simple POST to web service and retrieving the answer. All is done via JSON.

So far I managed to write this:

```
   public async static Task<string> SendJSONData(string urlToCall, string JSONData)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        try
        {

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(urlToCall, new StringContent(JSONData.ToString(),Encoding.UTF8,"application/json"));
            string res = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            return res;

        }
        catch
        {
            // error catching...
        }
```

But obviously no luck and I am pretty sure is bad. Thus I am unable to find any proper documentation on that.

In fact I am not sure it sends the POST in the right way and what I get from that "return res" is: System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]

The idea as said is to send a JSON array and to retrieve one from the same URL.

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Try `string res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`